# Functions not returning Print statements

Tags: python

Forgive me if this seems like a silly question, but I am currently in school for CS, and am just starting out in this course. Part of my lab is creating an actual program to run the Pseudo-code we created, and my code is not returning my Print statements. If anybody has an idea of what is causing the issue I would appreciate the help. After I input a numerical value, none of the Print statements are being displayed.

```
    #10.23.15
    #This program will demonstrate how to use decision
    #statements in Python

    #This program determines if a bonus should be awarded

    #The main function
    def main():
        print ("Welcome to the program")
        monthlySales = getSales() # gets sales

    #This function gets the monthly sales
    def getSales():
        monthlySales = input ("Enter the monthly sales $")
        monthlySales = float(monthlySales)
        return monthlySales

    #Function call to determine bonus
    def isBonus(monthlySales):
        if monthlySales >= 100000:
            print ("You have earned a $5,000 bonus!!!")

    #Function call to determine day off
    def dayOff(monthlySales):
        if monthlySales >= 112500:
            print ("All employees get one day off!")

    #calls main
    main()
```

Comment: "Not returning print statements". You don't return a print statement. You return, or you print.

Comment: It doesn't look like isBonus() and dayOff() get called at all. You get the value for monthlySales in main() but then don't do anything with it, including print it

Comment: Thanks for the help, I realize that I need to call those functions after reading your replies. I really appreciate the suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Python has some amazing [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.5/) that you'll want to refer to when writing your programs. If you're new to Python you should run through the tutorial, then refer to the library and language references as you need them (you can [read about print() here](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#print)).

Step through each line of your code. When you call main() at the very end, it enters your `def main():` block (nothing in your `def` blocks are actually run until they're called). `monthly_sales = getSales()` executes getSales(), which gets the sales input from your user, converts it to a float, and then returns that value to your `main()` function.

`main()` does nothing with the returned value, and your program exits. If you want to view the sales, you need a `print(monthlySales)` statement after your call to `getSales()`.